# "Solver did not exit normally"

Tags: python-3.8, pyomo, gurobi, python-3.9, glpk

I was running a code in python 3.7 but upgraded to 3.9, because python 3.7 didn't support the pickle protocol 5. When I'm trying to run the same code in 3.9 none of my solvers will work, both GLPK and Gurobi gives me the message:

```
raise ApplicationError(
pyutilib.common._exceptions.ApplicationError: Solver (glpk) did not exit normally

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py", line 601, in solve
    raise ApplicationError(
pyutilib.common._exceptions.ApplicationError: Solver (gurobi) did not exit normally
```

Have tried to update both of them with pip, Conda and their web software, but none of these solutions helps.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The OneDrive folder where the data was stored wasn't connected to Internet, so some of the parameter data had zero value, causing the objective function to get an inappropriate value, which again caused the solvers to not function. Have used both python 3.8 and 3.9 and the solvers work fine with both versions now.